# To use `dataset` or to use `webpy.database`?

Tags: python, mysql, web.py

I am using `webpy` to deal with web api things. And inside the program, we use `dataset` to connect to our `mysql` server.

Now the service sometimes throws this error: `TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30`. Is this happening because we're not using `webpy`'s internal database method?

Or, what's the advantage of using `webpy`'s `database` method over `dataset`?

---

- `dataset` package :  https://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- `webpy.database` :  http://webpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/db.html

---

Current code using `dataset`:

```
import dataset
import configs
db_host = configs.hosts['server']
db_url = 'mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8' % (db_host['user'], db_host['password'], db_host['ip'], db_host['database'])
db = dataset.connect(db_url)
```

Comment: How often do you open database sessions? Do you close them eventually?

Comment: Using `dataset`, there seems no such concept as `session`? I don't know how to close a session when using `dataset` to read/writer a database.

Comment: Every call to connect opens a new session. Can you show us your code, or at least the snippet where you call connect?